# Encrypt user AES keys with AWS KMS RSA key

Tags: rsa, aes, aes-gcm, pkcs1

I am developing a web application in which each user has some part of his data that is stored encrypted. We are hosted on AWS and I want to use KMS as part of the solution. To not make the solution overly expensive (AWS charges per key) I was thinking of the following solution:

1. I generate 1 RSA master key in AWS KMS
2. For each user I generate an AES key (to be used later in GCM mode) in my application and store it encrypted using the **public part** of my master key (using PKCS#1 v2 padding).
3. The user's data is encrypted using the AES key (GCM mode with random IV)
4. When working with the data I only need to request KMS to decrypt the user AES key, all operations after that are done with the decrypted AES key

Is anybody aware of somebody using a solution like this or any security pitfalls? Yes - if the master private key leaks we are in trouble, but that is on AWS to protect.

Comment: I'm almost having to think about a large scale solution where I didn't do something like this. We had a colleague who wanted all keys to be generated and stored by an HSM **all the time** (including e.g. the session keys within TLS), but that quickly turns into madness. For file based encryption I would even advice against storing the data keys in an HSM; your processor has likely AES-NI support, and I would strongly advice you to use it.

Comment: You might want to use a specific key wrap function for the AES stuff.  Also, keep in mind that there are limits to how much data can be encrypted with a single key using AES GCM (both in a single stream and over time).  Nearly 64 GB for the former and for the latter it depends on your risk tolerance, but generally about the same.

Comment: We are talking here about a few MB max. (<10)

Comment: The data keys would be generated by the app (not KMS) and stored encrypted (with that 1 KMS key) in a DB.